# how to implement typical use-case with recoil

Tags: recoiljs

I have a parent components, A, and child components B & C. I need to share a list between B & C, say a list of todos. Child C can add/delete an item in the todo list. Assume that the todo list is backed by an async service.

I have put together an app with A, B and C. My graph has the selected todo (set from a callback) atom and the list of current todos in its own atom. The current todo list is dependent on an id. When A mounts, I set a "id" from the URL (think routing). Since my views use the todo list recoil value, they get their list when its available.

When I click the delete button in C with a todo selected, I update the list on the server. But I want the recoil todo list to be refreshed after the request returns Ok that the todo was deleted. Or if I add a todo, I want to immediately add the todo to the list so its immediately viewable, add the todo on the server then fetch the todos in the background to refresh the recoil todo list.

How do I hand these last 2 parts in recoil?

Comment: Could you add all your code, please? I mean, all the components, the atoms, etc. Because answering your question using your code as a starring point is way faster than creating the "pre-requisite" code just to elaborate an answer. This allows checking if you use atoms/atomsFamily/selectors, etc. Strip out all the unnecessary code (like CSS, etc.) and paste an example (or the link to a working codesandbox), please 

Comment: I'll try to skinny something down. There are a few ToDo recoil apps out there such as https://dev.to/shubhamk/recoil-facebook-s-own-state-management-library-26pb and https://medium.com/swlh/recoil-facebooks-experimental-state-management-library-for-react-b588090c9e5c but they all look like they use strict, sync initialization on the todo array and none of them delete. Potentially, my list just needs to be state vs from a selector family query and it can get set from different places where the list is updated.

Comment: Yep, I know that your use-case is different, that's why I prefer working on your code instead of a generic one 

Comment: I'm going to close this out. I added a "version" counter to my recoil graph so that when a reference list changed (that kind of acts like a filter that can only be processed on the server)  is changed by the user, I update the counter and it forces a refresh of the core transaction data. This allows the reference list to be set explicitly both on initial render and after the successful update on the server which rerturns the reference list as well. It's either a "version" concept or a "successfully changed" state concept that was needed although I still feel like it should not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "version" or "successfully saved" recoil atom that can be used to trigger an update after data has been saved to the server. This will cause memory leaks though: https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil/issues/422